# Python program that crawls for external IP address

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, ip, web-crawler

I created a basic program to try and crawl a website for my external IP address with `BeautifulSoup 4`. Although, I keep getting an Attribute Error for my program because it can't obtain the string of a div class or whatever. It would appear as the specific div class does not exists and that it cannot therefore crawl it. I do know for a fact that it exists, even though it's saying it doesn't. Does anyone know what is wrong?

**Here is my code:**

```
import requests, sys, io
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address"
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer, "cp437", "backslashreplace")
sourcecode = requests.get(url)
plaintext = sourcecode.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plaintext, "html.parser")

tag = soup.find("span", {"style": "font-weight: bold; color:green;"})
print(tag)
ip = tag.string
print(ip)
```

Comment: There's not a single `span` element on that website.

Comment: When I inspect the element of the website, it says `<span style="font-weight: bold; color:green;">00.00.000.00</span>`

Comment: @Rawing It's a child element of `<p style="font-size:1.4em;" align="center">Your IP Address is <span style="font-weight: bold; color:green;">00.00.000.00</span>.</p>`

Comment: You're right, I just tried again and it loaded differently. Not sure why the website randomly changed.

Comment: I see it on the rendered page... Its probably being produced by javascript. I would load the page using selenium instead of requests before using beautifulsoup.

Comment: Perhaps there is a better way than crawling a website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Javascript, if you look at the source returned you can see:

```
<html style="height:100%"><head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"></head><body style="margin:0px;height:100%"><iframe src="/_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=24&xinfo=9-52943897-0 0NNN RT(1471643127529 69) q(0 -1 -1 -1) r(0 -1) B12(8,881022,0) U10000&incident_id=198001480102412051-472966643371608393&edet=12&cinfo=08000000" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 198001480102412051-472966643371608393</iframe></body></html>
```

They have detected that you are a bot and don't give you the source you expect.

You can get your ip and a lot more info using *wtfismyip.com* in json format:

```
url = "http://wtfismyip.com/json"
js = requests.get(url).json()
print(js)
```

Or just your ip using *httpbin*:

```
url = "http://httpbin.org/ip"
js = requests.get(url).json()
print(js)
```

Comment: On a side note, why does my external IP address stay the same across three different websites but they all give different locations for it? Like [wtfismyip](http://wtfismyip.com) says LA, but then [iplocation](https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address) says some town in Arkansas.

Comment: By using your method, it returns `{'origin': '00.00.000.00'}` so how would I just get the string 00.00.000.00?

Comment: `js["origin"]`, access like you would any dict

Answer (score 1):

As explained above that have bot detection mechanism placed on there servers and if you try to do requests.get  then it return "Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 415000500153648966-193432437842182947" and since source code is not loaded that you cannot find the required info. 
If you want to do it with beautifulsoup, with the help of selenium along with beautifulsoup you can get it, here is sample code:

if selenium is not installed than first do "pip install selenium" and download chromedriver from "https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads"

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("**Path to chrome driver**\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address')
content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
tag = soup.find("span", {"style": "font-weight: bold; color:green;"}).text
print(tag)
```

It will print: xxx.xx.xxx.xxx

Note: Some time When first time you launch the script on a new machine it might ask for a captcha, enter it manually and then the script will work